# How to rewrite a list based on an index?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have the following list:

```
listo = [['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'], 
         ['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81'],
         ['Audi', 'UK', 'Green', 'S1', '0', '2', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'], 
         ['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81'],
         ['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'], 
         ['BMW', 'NL', 'Black', 'S1', '0', '2', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81']]
```

I'am trying to re-create the list based on below code:

```
for l in listo:
    if l[5] == '1':    #<-- grab only the ones who have a 1 at index[5]
        del l[4:6]     #<-- delete the following rows
        del l[7:10]
        del l[-1]
        l[-1] = l[-1].lstrip('-')   #<-- remove the negative signs in index[-1] + index[-2]
        l[-2] = l[-2].lstrip('-')
        listo.append(l)             
        
print(listo)
```

**My current outcome:**

```
[['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'], 
['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'],       
['Audi', 'UK', 'Green', 'S1', '0', '2', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'],          
['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'], 
['BMW', 'NL', 'Black', 'S1', '0', '2', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81'], 
['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'], 
['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90']]
```

**My desired outcome:**

```
[['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'], 
['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90']]
```

Im not sure whats happening, it seems as if its appending the new list into the old list...

Comment: You are appending your list inside the current list. I'm not sure if that is the way to go...

Comment: You're appending to the list you're processing in the loop... append to a new list instead and the code works fine.

Comment: Why don't you append your output to a new list?

Comment: @Käseknacker Because I want my new list to have the same name as my old list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the new items in your current list. You would better use another list to save the new items and reassign it back to listo when loop is finished. See below:

```
temp=[]
for l in listo:
    if l[5] == '1':    #<-- grab only the ones who have a 1 at index[5]
        del l[4:6]     #<-- delete the following rows
        del l[7:10]
        del l[-1]
        l[-1] = l[-1].lstrip('-')   #<-- remove the negative signs in index[-1] + index[-2]
        l[-2] = l[-2].lstrip('-')
        temp.append(l)

listo=temp           
        
print(listo)
```

Output:

```
[['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'], 
['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'], 
['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90']]
```

Comment: IoaTzimas, cant I keep the name of the old list?

Comment: Yes, this is what my code does, at the end we have the items you want in the old-name list (bear in mind though that this way the rest items of listo will be lost)

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Don't forget to accept some answer, so that question will leave from "unanswered" queue. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`listo = [[*a[:4], a[6], a[7][1:]] for a in listo if a[5] == '1']`

```py
>>> listo = [['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'], 
         ['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81'],
         ['Audi', 'UK', 'Green', 'S1', '0', '2', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'], 
         ['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81'],
         ['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '0', '1', '80,7', '-1,90', '-35,19', '-35,73', '-35,4'], 
         ['BMW', 'NL', 'Black', 'S1', '0', '2', '80,4', '-1,04', '-35,73', '-35,72', '-35,81']]
>>> listo = [[*a[:4], a[6], a[7][1:]] for a in listo if a[5] == '1']
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(listo)
[['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'],
 ['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'],
 ['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'],
 ['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90']]
```

Notes:

1. `a` means one line in listo
2. `*a[:4]` retrieve first 4 elements of each line
3. `a[6]`, 7th element of each line
4. `a[7][1:]`, slice starting from the 2nd character of 8th element of
   each line, removing the first '-'.
5. `[*a[:4], a[6], a[7][1:]`, a new line
6. `for a[5] == '1'`, filter out any line whose 6th element if not '1'

Comment: Please consider adding more context/information instead of just a hard-to-read-one-liner.

Comment: Good idea. I'm a little confused why there is down vote, this might be the reason. Thanks. More comments added, and also the assignment to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list that overwrites your old.

It is more clear how your new list is assembled if you name the different parts.
(The names below I picked the name by chance, so perhaps they don't all match what they represent)

```
listo = [
     [brand, country, color, tag, A.lstrip('-'), B.lstrip('-')] 
     for brand, country, color, tag, _, index, A, B, *_ in listo
     if index is '1'
]

>> pprint(listo)

[['Audi', 'Ger', 'Yellow', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90'],
 ['Audi', 'Ger', 'Blue', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'],
 ['BMW', 'MR', 'Grey', 'S1', '80,4', '1,04'],
 ['BMW', 'ES', 'Black', 'S1', '80,7', '1,90']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the temporary list you can use this method. with the same list but I still prefer the solution of @IoaTzimas. which is simple and easy

```
for i  in range(len(listo)):
if listo[i][5] == '1':    #<-- grab only the ones who have a 1 at index[5]
    del listo[i][4:6]     #<-- delete the following rows
    del listo[i][7:10]
    del listo[i][-1]
    listo[i][-1] = listo[i][-1].lstrip('-')   #<-- remove the negative signs in index[-1] + index[-2]
    listo[i][-2] = listo[i][-2].lstrip('-')  
else:
    listo[i] = []
```

print(list(filter(None,listo)))

This also gives the same output